# Animar botão da ActionBar

Tags: android, actionbar

Boa tarde, 
Tenho uma aplicação que possui um botão de refresh na ActionBar :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:com.my.app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_refresh"
        android:title="@string/app_name"
        com.my.app:showAsAction="always"
          />
</menu>
```

Gostaria que ao clicar, iniciar uma Animação sobre o botão. 
Como ponto de partida, peguei um exemplo onde adiciona um `ProgressBar` no lugar do botão. Segue:

```
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId())
            {
                case R.id.action_refresh:
                    mRefreshAction = item;
                    mRefreshAction.setActionView(R.layout.menu_progress);
                    mRefreshAction.expandActionView();

                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

**menu_progress.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ProgressBar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</ProgressBar>
```

Este funcionou perfeitamente, então tentei trocar o `ProgressBar` por uma imagem e animá-la:

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.action_refresh:
                mRefreshAction = item;
                mRefreshAction.setActionView(R.layout.menu_progress);
                mRefreshAction.expandActionView();
                Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate);
                rotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
                mRefreshAction.getActionView().startAnimation(rotation);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
return true;
}
```

**menu_progress.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_refresh"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</ImageView>
```

Mas a imagem não é exibida!
Alguém saberia como animar uma imagem no **ActionBar**? 
Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma: Inclui a imagem dentro de um `LinearLayout` e funcionou corretamente.

Segue o código atualizado:

Como vou usar em várias telas, criei um classe abstrata para cuidar:

Java:

```
public  abstract  class LoaderModelActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected MenuItem mRefreshAction;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        this.mRefreshAction = menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh);
        boolean r = super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        onLoadAction();
        return r;
    }


    /**
     * Metodo abstrato que executa a ação da classe filha, logo que o menu estiver pronto
     */
    protected  abstract void onLoadAction();


    /**
     *Inicia a animação
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    public void startSyncMenu()
    {
        if(null == mRefreshAction)
        {
            return;
        }
        mRefreshAction.setActionView(R.layout.menu_progress);
        mRefreshAction.expandActionView();
        final Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate);
        rotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        // Anima-se a Imagem, pois e necessario um layout para corrigir a posicao
        ImageView.class.cast(mRefreshAction.getActionView().findViewById(R.id.progressBar2)).startAnimation(rotation);

    }

    /**
     * Para a animação
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    public void stopSyncMenu()
    {
        if(null == mRefreshAction)
        {
            return;
        }
        ImageView.class.cast(mRefreshAction.getActionView().findViewById(R.id.progressBar2)).clearAnimation();
        mRefreshAction.setActionView(null);
        mRefreshAction.expandActionView();
        mRefreshAction.collapseActionView();
    }

}
```

**menu_main.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:com.my.app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_refresh"
        android:title="@string/app_name"
        com.my.app:showAsAction="always"
        />

</menu>
```

**menu_progress.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_refresh"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_width="31dp"
        android:layout_height="31dp">
    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**rotate.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="600"
    android:fromDegrees="-360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" />
```

Saudações,